# Secured URL not filtered by Router

Tags: https, url, filter

I am blocking a website using router.It is working fine for non-secured URL but not working for secured URL(https).Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can block a website using URL or IP. Both ways can be used in http mode (clear text). However, you can block the website only using IP in https mode (encrypted). This is simply because the URL is also encrypted in https mode.

One way to block a website in https mode using its URL is to use a proxy server. Your users will send the requests to this proxy and this proxy can then block any website it is configured to do so.

Comment: The problem is we are using dynamic ip system. Can i do it for some range of IP's.For example i have to block "https:facebook.com". Thanks?

Comment: You can block all facebook IPs if you want, but your users can bypass this by using some proxy server.

Comment: Okay. I will try to block using IP address.

Comment: Even then, the IP range in use by facebook will eventually change. This is why you need a proxy that can MITM the SSL session and something like WCCP to redirect all traffic to your proxy internally thus preventing users from configuring their own proxy to bypass your rules.

Comment: @PaulAckerman: Yes, that's another point to consider.